# Pushing mail from postfix to iPhone

Tags: iphone, linux, email, push, postfix-mta

Is there anything out there (pref. open source) to push email to the iPhone like Exchange does?

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 3):

[Z-Push](http://z-push.sourceforge.net/soswp/) is an open source project that implements ActiveSync in PHP.  I've played with it works, it's not the greatest solution. 
BTW, I think you are confused about the part of the system that does the push, it's not Postfix.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll check it out. I may be getting the wrong end of the stick with the mail, I believe dovecot is the SMTP server which I suppose would push the mail to postfix which is the POP server? Is that correct?